# Copy Down Formulas to Last Row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel workbook that I run from a reporting tool.

In the worksheet "Data", in cells I2, J2, K2, L2, and M2 I have a formulas.

I am looking for a VBA script that will drag the formulas in these cells to where ever the last row may be. Col A can be used to determine the last row number.

I have been looking for a script that works, but I am struggling to find one. Please may someone assist me with this. Below screenshot of the static formulas that sit in these 5 cells.

[image]

```
Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(L2=1,IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2,0)),IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2-I1,0)))"
```

Comment: Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(L2=1,IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2,0)),IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2-I1,0)))". I'm not very skilled with VBA. This is not working

Comment: How are you getting `LastRow`? What is the value of it when you run that line of code and get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your formula works, maybe try :

```
Lastrow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("I2") = "=IF(L2=1,IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2,0)),IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2-I1,0)))"
Range("I2:I" & LastRow).FillDown
```

Comment: Thanks. I get a run time error 1004 "Method 'Range' of object _Global failed

Comment: @GrayMeiring same error as before ?

Comment: @GrayMeiring Try with the edit

Comment: Since column `I` is not yet populated, it does not make sense to use it to determine the last row.

Comment: @braX didn't saw screenshot, I switched column I to H

Comment: Thank you, this got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Enter the formula into I2 :

```
Range("I2").Formula = "=IF(L2=1,IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2,0)),IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2-I1,0)))"
```

Then use a separate line to autofill to last row

```
Range("I2").AutoFill Range("I2:I" & LastRow)
```

So like this :

```
    Range("I2").Formula = "=IF(L2=1,IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2,0)),IF(F2-E2>0,E2,IF(F2-E2<=0,F2-I1,0)))"
    Range("I2").AutoFill Range("I2:I" & LastRow)
```